# How can I purge members of a competitor's Facebook group from my own?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I help to run a parenting advice group on Facebook, where information is posted that can be taken out of context and abused. Unfortunately, that is exactly what is happening. In the group, parents are able to open up about their perceived shortcomings to ask for advice, and it can be embarrassing. This all works fine when contained inside of the group, but unfortunately there is another group that claims to be advocating for children's rights that routinely sends their members into our group to screenshot posts and criticize. We have had members of the group accused of child abuse and all manner of terrible things that are not even close to true under any interpretation of the word (Some of the accusations came after a post about whether or not it is okay to let your kids cry). To be ABSOLUTELY clear, we never advocate for anything that could be interpreted as child abuse under any circumstances, and none of that material is ever posted in the group. Regardless of that, the parent shaming coming from the rival group is so strong that parents feel uncomfortable sharing in our group, which defeats the purpose of it existing.

TLDR:
We need a solution to remove all members of a competing Facebook group from our Facebook group. The rival group instructs their members to join our group with fake accounts to screenshot posts. We have gotten a lot better at weeding out the fake accounts and preventing them from joining, but we need a solution to remove the accounts that are already in the group. We can't single out individual members, as the group is too large. Also, the members themselves aren't posting in the competing group. They send their screen shots to the moderator, who posts on their behalf. I have tried some webpage scraper tools to try and generate a list of names of people who like both of the pages, but haven't had much luck. The scraper only is able to get the first 20 names or so before quitting. Any suggestions? We have tried reporting the group and the offending posts, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is at least match the members in each group.

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/str/GROUP_ID_1/members/GROUP_ID_2/members/intersect
```

That should give who is in both groups

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/str/GROUP_ID_1/members/PAGE_ID_1/likers/intersect
```

The above should give those group members who liked a specific page.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. I used the group id which I got from this tutorial https://www.slickremix.com/how-to-get-your-facebook-group-id/ and I got the page ID from findmyfbid.com. Is that correct?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/search/str/1808709579381249/members/485112611598695/likers/intersect